# When referencing two variables perl returns Use of uninitialized value

Tags: perl, windows-7, strawberry-perl

I have two directories in one directory is file HG111_1_001.txt, in the other  directory is HG111_2_001.txt. This two files need to processed through a set of commands (sub single and sub double) and then brought back as a pair to sub playnice. The issue I'm having is as follows:

The code returns the following ambiguous warning:
Use of uninitialized value $file2 in string at C:\Users\prl\tools.pl line 52.
This would be the final print line.

When use Carp is enabled this error indicates  that:
main::playnice(HG111_2_001.txt called at line 37 and
main::playnice(HG111_1_001.txt called at line 21

Where these are the lines corresponding to when I pass the value to the sub.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $dirname  = 'C:\Users\prl';
my $dirname2 = 'C:\Users\prl\1';

my $file1;
my $file2;

#Read Directory and find first file
opendir( D, $dirname2 ) or die "can't opendir $dirname: $!";
while ( $file2 = readdir(D) ) {

    next unless $file2 =~ m/^HG111_1_0/;

    my $path2 = "$dirname2\\$file2";
    single( $file2, $path2 );
    playnice($file2);
}

#Pass to first sub
sub single {
    my $file2 = shift;
    my $path2 = shift;
    print "$path2\n";
    print "$file2\n";
}

opendir( DIR, $dirname ) or die "can't opendir $dirname: $!";
while ( $file1 = readdir(DIR) ) {
    next unless $file1 =~ m/^HG111_2_0/;
    my $path2 = "$dirname\\$file1";

    double( $file1, $path2 );
    playnice($file1);

}

sub double {
    my $file1 = shift;
    my $path1 = shift;
    print "$path1\n";
    print "$file1\n";
}

sub playnice {
    my $file1 = shift;
    my $file2 = shift;

    print "$file1", "$file2", "\n", 'orked?';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you pass only one argument to your playnice function...

See this simple example:

```
sub playnice {
  my ($f1,$f2) = @_;
  print "$f1 $f2\n";
}

# your program: wrong, $f2 is undef
playnice('foo'); # one argument

# what it should do
playnice('foo','bar') # two argument
```

now you have to edit your code and call the playnice function with two arguments.

also you should:

- consider putting all your subroutines at the same place (at the
  beginning/end of the program);
- tell us clearly the purpose of this program;
- clean your code (add indentation and comments)

Comment: Do you mind providing the non-laconic version of your answer?

Comment: you call your playnice function with only one argument. that's why $file2 is undefined

Comment: I seem to have caught your drift

Comment: the problem is not how you retrieve the arguments inside your playnice function, but how you pass the arguments to the function. you should call your function with something like : playnice($arg1,$arg2)

Comment: Also Thank you Pierre

Comment: @user3050913 - [Pierre](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1069567/pierre) isn't *literally* suggesting `playnice($arg1, $arg2)` but rather showing that you need to pass two (initialized) `arg`uments to your `playnice` subroutine.  At the top of your program, consider `my $file1 = ''; my $file2 = '';` and then `playnice($file1, $file2);` throughout.

Comment: @Kenosis I'm still not understanding :(  I edited teh call out of the  while loops and  am now calling playnice ($f1, $f2); followed by sub playnice{ my $f1=shift; my $f2 = shift; print "$f1 $f2 \n";} and the response one that there are uninitialized values in my print comand

Comment: @user3050913 - You need to send `playnice` the variables whose content you want it to print.  If one of the variables you send to `playnice` hasn't been initialized, a `Use of uninitialized value ...` will occur.  Thus, `playnice ($f1, $f2);` is fine, provided that both `$f1` and `$f2` have been initialized.  Your `playnice` subroutine doesn't care about the names of the variables you send to it.